# finding $cov(X,Y)$

Tags: statistics

suppose $X\sim N(0,1)$ , $Y = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} X, & \hbox{if } |X|\geq a, \\ -X, & \hbox{if }|X|< a. \end{array} \right. $
how can find $cov(X,Y)$.
$\phi,\Phi$  are density function and distribution function standard normal